# Character set encoding for serial connection in putty

Tags: character-encoding, serial-port, putty, at-command

I have connected a gsm/gprs modem to the putty terminal on windows 7 for serial communication. The AT commands work but the response from the modem is displayed as special characters which is not readable. Both the port and the modem is configured at 9600 baud. I changed the character encoding to utf-8 (Window->translation->character set) but the results were the same.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The character encoding of strings sent to/from the modem is controlled with the `AT+CSCS` command, Select TE character set. If you want UTF-8 run `AT+CSCS="UTF-8"`. You can check current selected character set with `AT+CSCS?` and supported sets with `AT+CSCS=?`. See the [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) specification for more details.